# Connection to PostgreSQL installed with scoop on Windows

Tags: postgresql

I installed Postgresql with [scoop](https://scoop.sh/).
To start the installed PostgreSQL, I cd to `C:\Users\my_user_name\scoop\apps\postgresql\current\bin` directory and run `postgres.exe` what gives me the following output in the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\my_user_name>C:\Users\my_user_name\scoop\apps\postgresql\current\bin\postgres.exe
2022-09-30 12:50:05.195 GMT [17456] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.5, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
2022-09-30 12:50:05.203 GMT [17456] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2022-09-30 12:50:05.203 GMT [17456] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2022-09-30 12:50:05.526 GMT [7656] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-09-30 12:49:40 GMT
2022-09-30 12:50:06.504 GMT [17456] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

I believed that the default user name is `postgres`, but does seem to work.
Running some commands in another command prompt window raises the error:

```
psql -u postgres
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist

# trying to use my Windows username instead:
psql -u my_windows_username
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "my_windows_username" does not exist
```

In the Postgres connection window there are the same errors:

```
2022-09-30 12:50:05.195 GMT [17456] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.5, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
2022-09-30 12:50:05.203 GMT [17456] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2022-09-30 12:50:05.203 GMT [17456] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2022-09-30 12:50:05.526 GMT [7656] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-09-30 12:49:40 GMT
2022-09-30 12:50:06.504 GMT [17456] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2022-09-30 12:50:31.204 GMT [10812] FATAL:  role "my_windows_username" does not exist
2022-09-30 12:50:31.499 GMT [2312] FATAL:  role "my_windows_username" does not exist
2022-09-30 12:51:18.550 GMT [14492] FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
2022-09-30 12:58:58.058 GMT [18144] FATAL:  role "my_windows_username" does not exist
```

Any thoughts about how to fix that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I installed postgres using

```
scoop install postgresql
```

Then, I have started postgresql using following command

```
pg_ctl start
```

Login is successful with following command in another cmd/powershell window:

```
psql --username=postgres
```

or

```
 psql -U postgres
```

According to help, psql --help, you need to use either

```
psql -U username or psql --username=username
```